# Error occurred npm command via ssh (Cygwin)

Tags: node.js, bash, ssh, npm, cygwin

On my MacOSX (10.11.6), I tried to execute `npm ls` command to Cygwin's bash (Windows10) via `ssh`, but below error occurred.

```
# npm ls
Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${APPDATA}
   at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:418:13
   at RegExp.[Symbol.replace] (native)
   at RegExp.[Symbol.replace] (native)
   at String.replace (native)
   at envReplace (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:414:12)
   at parseField (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:392:7)
   at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:335:17
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at Conf.add (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:334:23)
   at ConfigChain.addString (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:244:8)

Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${APPDATA}
   at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:418:13
   at RegExp.[Symbol.replace] (native)
   at RegExp.[Symbol.replace] (native)
   at String.replace (native)
   at envReplace (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:414:12)
   at parseField (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:392:7)
   at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:335:17
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at Conf.add (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:334:23)
   at ConfigChain.addString (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:244:8)
```

So I tried to execute other npm commands (ex. `npm install`, etc.), but the result was same error.
If I executed npm commands on Cygwin console, it worked normally.
Moreover, on MacOSX I executed a command other than npm to Cygwin via `ssh`, it also looked fine.
(When I login via `ssh`, Cygwin cannot load some paths normally...?)
What is the reason for this?

Info.

```
# node -v
v6.9.4

# npm -v
Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${APPDATA}
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:418:13
    at RegExp.[Symbol.replace] (native)
    at RegExp.[Symbol.replace] (native)
    at String.replace (native)
    at envReplace (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:414:12)
    at parseField (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:392:7)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:335:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Conf.add (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:334:23)
    at ConfigChain.addString (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:244:8)

3.10.10

# uname -rv
2.6.1(0.305/5/3) 2016-12-16 11:55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to Cygwin's SSH server, you don't get a login environment in the same way that you do when you open a console with your own existing logon session. Apparently, this is an insurmountable limitation.  One of the developers [writes](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-08/msg00238.html):

> The child process started by sshd inherits its minimal environment from
>   its sshd server parent process.  The sshd server is running under
>   another account and so has another set of environment variables.  The
>   setuid() call does not change the environment.  There's no mechanism to
>   fetch a user-specific environment.

---

The reason you are seeing this error is because you have something referencing `${APPDATA}` in your config (`~/.npmrc`).  You can either change the config to not rely on this variable, or you can set the variable in your SSH session, for example:

```
export APPDATA="$SYSTEMDRIVE\\Users\\$USERNAME\\AppData\\Roaming"
```